# Getting specific distinct record to a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've been using this:

```
return myListOfContacts.DistinctBy(e => e.Id).Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId).ToList();
```

Which returns a distinct list, as requested. The problem is, when the records are duplicate, the returned record is the first on the list.

For example, if in my contacts I have these:

[Id - ContactId - Name - FlagIWantThisOne]

```
1 - 99 - John - true
2 - 56 - Mike - false
2 - 56 - Mike - true
3 - 13 - Dave - false
```

It returns 3 records:

> John, Mike and Dave.

But the "Mike" record I want is the one with the flag as true.

In all, if a record is duplicate, the list should return the one with the flag set to true and ignore the others.

I got the `distinctBy` there, but it is returning the first one it finds on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try:

```
myListOfContacts.GroupBy(e => e.Id)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.FlagIwantThisOne).First())
                .ToList();
```

The logic is:

Group by Id. Then, sort through group descending (true > false), and take the first one from each group.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering the list first should help. Also, I would put the where clause at first, for performance reasons:

```
return myListOfContacts.Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId)
                       .OrderBy(e => e.Flag)
                       .DistinctBy(e => e.Id)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than ordering the grouping elements, which is O(N*log(N)) time complexity you can use simple O(N) search plus fallback to the original logic:

```
return myListOfContacts
    .Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Id, (key, elements) =>
        elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FlagIWantThisOne) ?? elements.First())                   .OrderBy(e => e.Flag)
    .ToList();
```

It basically does *In all, if a record is duplicate, the list should return the one with the flag set to true and ignore the others."*

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the list:

```
return myListOfContacts
    .Reverse()
    .DistinctBy(e => e.Id)
    .Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId)
    .ToList();
```

But I really think you should avoid duplicate records.